# C# closing another form problem, Close(); does not work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, formclosing

I have this code on form1

```
TimerMode f2 = new TimerMode();
f2.show();
```

now I'm trying to use this code in some point in time, but nothing happens?
Cmd = Closing

```
public void DoActions(string Cmd)
{
  switch(Cmd){

  case"Open":
      TimerMode f2 = new TimerMode();
      f2.show()
      break;
  case"Closing":
       f2.Close();
       break;
}
}
```

do you have any idea why its not closing?.

what I really want it to close it.

in vb6 I use this

```
unload form2
```

Comment: Where are you calling `f2.Close()`? In the same place you create the form?

Comment: umm, actually f2.close is on another method that i call when im trying to close it. NOTE: i edited the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably a threading issue. Try this:

```
f2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => f2.Close()));
```

If that doesn't work, use below modification:

```
public TimerMode f2 = new TimerMode();
public void DoActions(string Cmd)
{
  switch(Cmd){    
  case"Open":          
      f2.show()
      break;
  case"Closing":
       f2.Close();
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Teoman, i tried what you said. i dont know why but when i run it. it just stays there. if i run it again. it just stays there (the yellow highlight when debugging)

Comment: Teoman Your my Hero! =*, i dont know why but can you please explain a little why it now work? and my problem is a threading issue? really thank you!

Comment: @Katherina: it works because f2 is not a local variable now. It's a field on the form class. Once a method returns, its local variables are forgotten, and once you call it again, different local variables are used. Now that f2 is a field, f2 is not forgotten. It's always the same f2 whenever you call the method.

Comment: What Martinho says is true. Just make sure that you declare form varialbes inside the class not inside the method so you can later access them (i.e. for closing it).

Comment: i see.. now that makes it more clearer. thanks for the short tutorial. it really help beginners like me

Answer (score 0):

I just spent hours wondering why my form wont close. Turns out, I forgot to check everything under

Debug->Exceptions

so one of the eventhandlers silently threw a NullPointerException that got caught by the Framework otherwise. I guess that sets the Cancel property of the event arguments to true and setting it to false afterwards does obviously not do the trick (When I fixed the NullPointer, everything worked normal again.).